# How can a robots.txt ignore anything with action=history in it?

Tags: seo, wiki, mediawiki, robots.txt

I have a MediaWiki, and I don't think I want Google indexing the history of any page. How can a `robots.txt` disallow URLs with `action=history` in the query string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTML for the history view (and several others, such as the logs, etc.) contains a "noindex,nofollow" meta declaration. Compliant user agents, such as Googlebot, will honour this advice and not bother indexing the page.